# What is the best approach to passing data to a custom binding handler

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm working on a few knockout.js binding handlers in my spare time for some current/future projects I will be doing and I was wondering what the best approach to passing multiple parameters is. [Link to example bindings](http://johngafford.com/KnockoutAnimate/) (Not for production use)

For example, I have a "cssAnimateVisible" binding handler that looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind="cssAnimateVisible: isCssAnimateVisible">Animation</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
self.isCssAnimateVisible = ko.observable(false);
```

I can turn the observable off and on and it will play whatever default animation I want it to play on that element. Most of the time, this works just fine and dandy. However, if I want to change the default animation to something other than bouncing in and out I have to do this:

```
<div data-bind="cssAnimateVisible: { observable: isCssAnimateVisible, animation: 'flipInY', animationOut: 'flipOutY'}">Animation</div>
```

As you can see, I'm passing in a lot more variables since I do not want to use the default animation for this particular element. This approach is what I currently have on my project site, but I don't like passing in a variable called "observable" because that just seems to bloat up the html controls, so I have narrowed it down to this:

```
<div data-bind="cssAnimateVisible: isCssAnimateVisible, animation: 'flipInY', animationOut: 'flipOutY'">Animation</div>
```

As you can see, it is a lot shorter than above, but it does take the other parameters out of the context of "cssAnimateVisible", which could be a potential downside due to naming conflicts with other custom bindings someone might have.

Moreover, I thought about just passing variables like this:

```
<div data-bind="cssAnimateVisible: { isCssAnimateVisible, 'flipInY', 'flipOutY' }">Animation</div>
```

This makes it even shorter with the expense of having to know the order of the parameters being passed in.

Lastly, I thought about just creating a lot of different binding handlers for the various animations in the animate.css library like so:

```
<div data-bind="cssBounceVisible: isCssAnimateVisible1">Animation</div>
<div data-bind="cssFlipVisible: isCssAnimateVisible2">Animation</div>
<div data-bind="cssLightSpeedVisible: isCssAnimateVisible3">Animation</div>
```

This approach increases the lines of code in my project along with not giving as much flexibility. Still, it is probably the shortest data-bind of them all.

Does anyone know the best approach to handling this? I want to be consistent in my approach more than anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is a opinion based term, but there is also a technical difference between wrapping the data bound observable in a object literal or using seperate binding names for each observable.

If you want to support writing to none observables then you need to use seperate binding names for each observable you want to bind, otherwise `ko.expressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty` wont be able to write the none observables.